# php google ads api - unauthorized_client

Tags: php, google-ads-api, google-client

I'm using 'Google_Client' class to authenticate access to adwords api so:

```
$REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost/GoogleAdwords/auth.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("App name");

$SCOPES = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'  
      );
  $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT_URI);
  $client->setScopes($SCOPES);

try{
            $oauth2 = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
                    ->withClientId($OAuthCredentials['clientId'])
                    ->withClientSecret($OAuthCredentials['clientSecret'])
                    ->withRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken())
                    ->build();

            }catch(Exception $err){
        //redirect("auth.php");
                 echo $err;
            }
```

After authentication:

```
$oauth2 = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
                    ->withClientId($OAuthCredentials['clientId'])
                    ->withClientSecret($OAuthCredentials['clientSecret'])
                    ->withRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken())
                    ->build();
  $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
                    ->fromFile()    
                    ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2)                
                    ->build();

$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
        $managedCustomerService = $adWordsServices->get($session, ManagedCustomerService::class);



        $selector = new Selector();
        $selector->setFields(['CustomerId', 'Name']);
        $selector->setOrdering([new OrderBy('CustomerId')]);


        try{
        $mccAccounts = $managedCustomerService->get($selector);
        }catch(Exchange $e){
            // echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

I'm pretty sure that the client is authenticated as I can get refreshToken and access token. But I'm getting this error:

```
 Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized" }
```

What could be the problem here? Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Using the same $client to access user information and shopping content works fine, but that's not the case for adwords.

Comment: Are you using a library if so which one?

Comment: ah I'm using this https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client for my Google_Client class and also GoogleAds PHP API https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib

Comment: basically, I want to access Google Adwords using Google PHP client api.

Comment: Please consider using this library instead: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib. In the examples folder, you should find examples on how to connect to Adwords.

Comment: Yes we use that on our project but we also want to get information from Content Shopping API. That's why we want to use Google API Php client.

Comment: getting product info such as product title, sizes, color, etc is not possible with GoogleAds PHP lib, right?

Comment: solving the same problem now... was there any solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but I don't understand Google's libraries well enough to say if it's all necessary, maybe someone else can trim the fat.

```php
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('NAME_HERE');
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/../Credentials/oauth.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApiFormatV2(2);
//// Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
$oAuth = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../Credentials/oauth.json'), true);
$accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../Credentials/token.json'), true);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$oauth2 = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
    ->withClientId($oAuth['installed']['client_id'])
    ->withClientSecret($oAuth['installed']['client_secret'])
    ->withRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken())
    ->build();

$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
    ->withDeveloperToken('TOKEN_HERE')
    ->withClientCustomerId("CUSTOMER_ID_HERE")
    ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2)
    ->build();

$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
$managedCustomerService = $adWordsServices->get($session, ManagedCustomerService::class);

$selector = new Selector();
$selector->setFields(['CustomerId', 'Name']);
$selector->setOrdering([new OrderBy('CustomerId')]);
$mccAccounts = $managedCustomerService->get($selector);

dd($mccAccounts) ;
```